# Mock Iframe element in Jasmine and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, iframe, jasmine

I am writing a directive unit test using `jasmine` to test whether  the directive in question when applied on an iframe element, would actually bind all the children elements of the iframe(`documentContent` children actually).

What here is really hard to simulate is the actual iframe element. Executing the test where the iframe would really have to load external website could take a lot of time. Is there maybe an alternative solution, instead of using real frame element ?

Comment: Why not simulate the external website with a local page that loads faster? - you are not testing the external website, right?

Comment: You are completely right, I don't know how I didn't think of it. Thanks.